# Apache VirtualHost Issues

Tags: php, apache, laravel, virtualhost

I have two installations of laravel. One in a folder called **"laravel"** and the second in a folder called "**learningLaravel"**. Both of them are siblings in the same parent folder. Before i installed **"learningLaravel"** i used to access the site in **"laravel"** through *localhost/laravel/public*, and everything works fine .

After i installed **"learningLaravel"**, i decided to create a virtual host for it on my WAMP server with the name **"learningLaravel.dev"** . My [windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts] file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
// I added this entry. The first two entries above was already there
127.0.0.1       learninglaravel.dev
```

I added the following to my Apache "httpd-vhosts.conf"::

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/learningLaravel/public"
    ServerName learningLaravel.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Now i can access **"learningLaravel"** through **learningLaravel.dev**. But when i want to access the site in the **"laravel"** folder through *localhost/laravel/public*, i get a message ::

```
Not Found
The requested URL /laravel/public was not found on this server.
```

I try *localhost* also and i get ::

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

The problem i have now is anything that begins with localhost doesn't work, but **learningLaravel.dev** works.

What changes do i need to make? thanks.

Comment: `<VirtualHost learninglaravel.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/learningLaravel/public"
    ServerName learningLaravel.dev
</VirtualHost>`
Can you try this?

Comment: I am unsure whether how it is the case, but I believe when you just had **laravel** it was the only "domain" available and thus always the one displayed, but since you have added another "domain" and haven't (at least from the information given), not added the **laravel** to the config, it can no longer find it as there are now two domains, and only one configured.

Comment: 127.0.1.1       learninglaravel.dev add this to your host file instead of what you have, restart apache and it should work

Comment: @SiimKallari  When i test learninglaravel.dev, i get the following error message in the browser (Forbidden, 
You don't have permission to access / on this server)

Comment: Read up from google how to set up vhost you need to grant allow access all to cfg file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define 2 virtual hosts:

- The first catches all domains which don't have their own virtual host. In this example these are `domain1.dev`, `domain2.dev`, `domain3.dev` and `localhost`.
- The second host catches the domain `learninglaravel.dev`

#### httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost learninglaravel.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/learningLaravel/public"
    ServerName learninglaravel.dev
    ServerAlias *.learninglaravel.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

#### windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       learninglaravel.dev
# you don't need the following this is just for explanation:
127.0.0.1       domain1.dev
127.0.0.1       domain2.dev
127.0.0.1       domain3.dev
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the two two virtual hosts and "learninglaravel.dev" works fine. But "localhost/laravel/public" gives me the following message "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." I didn't change my .../etc/hosts file. It remains the same. I don't think i have to change anything in it, or?  Another question is why is the ServerName for both virtualhosts the same "*.localhost"

Comment: forgot to change the server name after coyp paste :). The "Whoops" message is from laravel. That means your virtual host config is correct now, but there are still some issues in your laravel config. Maybe it is because of the vhost is not pointing to the `public/` directory. Maybe there are some `.httaccess` configs needed or define a third host `laravel.dev` pointing to `c:/wamp/www/Laravel/public` (and add it to your `hosts` file too). At least apache is working fine now.

Comment: I have added "laravel.dev" to the /etc/hosts file and also an entry to the Apache httpd-vhosts.conf file and everything works now.  Thanks for your help.